# sed : Ignore line starting whitespace for match

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I want to replace the default listening port of httpd to 9090. I can edit the line in httpd.conf file using below

```
sed -i "/^Listen/c\Listen 9090" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But the line

```
Listen 80
```

may have white space before it.

How do I ignore this white space to match this line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your matching pattern no catch white spaces before liste in the following way:

```
/^\s*Listen/
```

That will include all

```
Listen ..
    Listen ...
```

and others.

Comment: Matching exactly as required. But it will eat up the white space in the replacement as well. But that should not be a problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can put the whitespace in a group and use that in the replacement. For example, `s/^(\s*)Listen(.*)$/\1Listen/` (or something much like it; try it before you use it on anything valuable).

Comment: Thanks Michael that's exactly what I was hoping for. Small fix: the parentheses must be escaped as so:  s/^\\(\s*\\)Listen(.*)$/\1Listen/

Comment: @pmont with gnu sed you can use `sed -r` instead escaping.

Answer (score 9):

Just allow the regular expression to match whitespace as well. You can use either the character group `[ \t]` (which matches the space or tab characters) or the [equivalent POSIX bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) `[:blank:]`.

Hence, `/^Listen/` becomes `/^[[:blank:]]*Listen/`. (Note that the bracket expression is effectively written with a double square bracket pair.)

Comment: Working perfectly. And same as the accepted answer, except that the accepted answer is more readable. Thanks!